# Filter and search both option in a list react/react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a list that has an option for searching and filtering.
Example

```
const users = [
  {
    id: '54545',
    name: 'john wick',
    status: 'ACTIVE',
  },
  {
    id: '54546',
    name: 'john wick2',
    status: 'DELETED',
  },
  {
    id: '54547',
    name: 'john wick3',
    status: 'SUSPENDED',
  },
];
```

Search is performed on the basis of *name* and filtering is performed on the basis of *status*
Now there is a function named getUsers which returns the data used to render the list item

```
// returns filteredUsers or searchedUsers if they exists otherwise returns the Users
const getUsers = () => filteredUsers || searchedUsers || users

.
.
.
<List data={getUsers()} />
```

So, basically the filteredUsers has priority over the searchedUsers
Whenever a user performs the filter operation filteredUsers are shown.
Now there are 2 constraints.

1. User should be able to search and after searching, can apply the filters(this is handled by the above-mentioned code of getUsers() as the filter has priority over the search, therefore, filtered users will be rendered)
2. The user can apply filtered and after that, he performs a search and the search result will be shown(This can't be performed by the above-mentioned code of getUsers() as in this case there are both filteredUserts and searchedUsers and filter have the priority over the search, therefore, searched users will not be rendered).

How can I implement point 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use State to handle filtering and search

snak: https://snack.expo.io/bOrYw9mSF

check this code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const USERS = [
  {
    id: '54545',
    name: 'john wick',
    status: 'ACTIVE',
  },
  {
    id: '54546',
    name: 'john wick2',
    status: 'DELETED',
  },
  {
    id: '54547',
    name: 'john wick3',
    status: 'SUSPENDED',
  },
  {
    id: '32434',
    name: 'Spiderman',
    status: 'ACTIVE',
  },
];
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    users: USERS,
    seacrhText: '',
    filterBy: null,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (state.filterBy) {
    setState({ ...state, users: filterBy(state.users) });
    } else {
      if (state.seacrhText) {
        setState({
          ...state,
          users: serachusers(USERS)
        })
      } else {
        setState({
        ...state, 
        users: USERS
      })
      }
    }
  }, [state.filterBy]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (state.seacrhText) {
    setState({ ...state, users: serachusers(state.users) });
    } else {
      if (state.filterBy) {
        setState({
          ...state,
          users: filterBy(USERS)
        })
      } else {
        setState({
        ...state, 
        users: USERS
      })
      }
    }
  }, [state.seacrhText]);

  const filterBy = (users) => {
    if (state.filterBy) {
      return users.filter(({ status }) => status === state.filterBy);
    } else {
      return users;
    }
  };

  const serachusers = (users) => {
    if (state.seacrhText) {
      return users.filter((user) =>
        user.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(state.seacrhText)
      );
    } else {
      return users;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Filter By</Text>
      <View style={styles.fiters}>
        {['ACTIVE', 'DELETED', 'SUSPENDED'].map((val) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
            onPress={() => {
              setState({
                ...state,
                filterBy: state.filterBy === val ? null : val,
              });
            }}>
            <CheckBox value={state.filterBy === val} />
            <Text>{val}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          height: 50,
          borderWidth: 0.4,
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          borderColor: '#ccc',
        }}
        onChangeText={(seacrhText) => {
          setState({
            ...state,
            seacrhText,
          });
        }}
        placeholder="Search wiht name"
      />
      {/*<Button
        title="Search"
        onPress={() => {
          setState({
            ...state,
            users: serachusers(state.seacrhText),
          });
        }}
      />*/}
      <ScrollView>
        {state.users.map(({ name, status }, key) => (
          <View
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'stretch',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginVertical: 10,
            }}>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
            <Text style={{ marginLeft: 20, fontSize: 10 }}>{status}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is if I've got a search that is searching onChangeText? 
The example you described will update the state on each change and what if the user clears the search text? How will you show the list which was before the search ?

Comment: Check the snack if the search text is empty it returns all the users https://snack.expo.io/bOrYw9mSF

Comment: But if the filter is applied and the searched is performed after that then when search text is empty we'll return the original list but it needs to be the filtered one.

Comment: @Froxxx I updated my code check it out and let me know, I tested and everything was working fine

Answer (score 0):

You should make it a two steps process rather than one.

```
const filteredUsers = getFilteredUsers(users);
const searchedUsers = getSearchedUsers(filteredUsers);
```

in `getSearchedUsers` if `search.length==0` return original users

else filter the required according to search text.